# How to scan multiple Git repositories with JQAssistant Git plugin in one shot?

Tags: git, plugins, jqassistant

I have a situation with structure bellow and Git plugin plus property file scanner. There are N Git repositories under "Parent_Directory". I am not able to scan "Parent_Directory" in one shot because Git plugin is expecting one .git folder per scan.  So I have to scan repositories one by one which doesn't look a big issue.

```
Parent_Directory
 |- Repository_A
 |  |- .git
 |  |- Folder
 |     |- File.properties
 |- Repository_B
    |- .git
    |- Folder
       |- File.properties
```

The challenge is if there are property files with same folder structure and file name (ie Folder/File.properties) in different repositories, I'm not able to identify which repository they belong to. It works fine
with nodes which are pointing to Git repositories, so I can associate them to ":Repository" node and figure our where do they belong to. But properties are not. There is no node with :Git:Properties label.

Overall you will have ":File" nodes which are not labeled with ":Git" and query below finds many of them

```
MATCH (n:File)
WHERE NOT n:Git 
RETURN n
```

Seems it happens when we use Git plugin plus scanners for Json, Yaml, XML, properties, etc.

I have two questions:

- Is there a workaround to scan multiple repositories in one shot by scanning their parent directory.
- If not, is there a way to give instructions to Git plugin to cover all files when other scanners are also involved.

Comment: This question is in context of JQAssistant tool and its Git plugin: https://github.com/kontext-e/jqassistant-plugins/blob/master/git/src/main/asciidoc/git.adoc

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense (with the updated title).

Answer (score 1):

The Git plugin prevents scanning the same Git repository more than one time as it can happen in multi-module Maven projects. Unfortunately there is currently (version 1.8.0) no workaround for this. The only option you have is to run jQAssistant a second time, now giving only the missing Git repository to scan:

```
jqassistant.cmd scan -f .\Parent_Directory\Repository_B\.git\
```